# Why highchart stock is not accepting the series and throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, highchartstock

> I am implementing Highchart stock for the first time. But it is throwing a gapsize  error the error is "caught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'gapSize')". I searched alot but didn't found any solution. Help me to solve this error.

`MY CODE IS`

```
import React from "react"; 
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock"; 
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official"; 
import { Box } from "@mui/material"; 
import NoDataToDisplay from "highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display";

function StockChart(props) { NoDataToDisplay(Highcharts);

const Options = { 
chart: { 
  backgroundColor: "transparent", 
  type: props.type, 
  height: props.height ? props.height : "400px", 
  zoomType: props.zoom ? "x" : undefined, 
},
title: {
  text: props.title,
  align: "left",
},

subtitle: {
  text: props.subtitle,
  align: "left",
},

rangeSelector: {
  buttons: [
    {
      type: "day",
      count: 1,
      text: "1d",
    },
    {
      type: "day",
      count: 3,
      text: "3d",
    },
    {
      type: "week",
      count: 1,
      text: "1w",
    },
    {
      type: "all",
      text: "All",
    },
  ],
  selected: 0,
  inputEnabled: true,
},

series: props.series,

legend: {
  enabled: true,
},
xAxis: {
  type: "datetime",
},

yAxis: [
  {
    labels: {
      align: "right",
      x: -3,
    },
    title: {
      text: "Mega Watts",
    },
    height: "60%",
    lineWidth: 2,
    resize: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
  {
    labels: {
      align: "right",
      x: -3,
    },
    title: {
      text: "MCP",
    },
    top: "65%",
    height: "35%",
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2,
  },
],

credits: {
  enabled: false,
},

lang: {
  noData: "Data not available...",
},
noData: {
  style: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "20px",
    color: "#303030",
  },
},
}; return ( <Box pl={"10px"} border={1px solid ${props.borderColor}} borderRadius="5px" backgroundColor="#fff" \> <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} constructorType={"stockChart"} options={Options} /> </Box> ); }

export default StockChart;
```

The react component is called here:

```
{monthAnalyticsData.status ? (
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              height: "350px",
            }}
          >
            <CircularProgress />
          </Box>
        ) : (
          <StockChart title="Monthly Chart" series={monthAnalyticsData.sData} />
        )}
```

I searched on stack overflow and read Highchart stock API but didn't find any solution for my question.

Comment: Hi @PALLAVI DWIVEDI, That's probably because you've set `type: props.type` which is undefined. Please check this live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-cf2ps1?file=/demo.jsx Also, it is better to initialize all modules outside of a component function.